# Commutator of field operator with function of number operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

Consider the commutator

$$\left[\hat{a},\sqrt{1-\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}}\right].$$

Because $\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}=\hat{n}$ is the familiar number operator, and $[\hat{a},\hat{n}]=\hat{a}$, I would expect that there is a simple expression for the commutator above. However, I don't see it, and writing out the square root with a series expansion seems very messy.

Is there a simple way to address this commutator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\hat{a} f(\hat{n})= f(\hat{n}+1)\hat{a}$,  so that
$$\left[\hat{a}, f(\hat{n})  \right]= \Bigl (f(1+\hat{n})- f(\hat{n})\Bigr )~ \hat{a} \\
=  \hat{a}  \Bigl (f(\hat{n})- f(\hat{n}-1)\Bigr )   .$$

Note its action on $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, ...

Comment: Thanks! A bit curious though that applying it to my f above requires choosing a branch cut.

Comment: Indeed, it is your function's "fault". There are creative workarounds in many such situations.

Comment: yes, what you have now addad as a second line circumvents the problem. Was about to do that :)